# How to calculate GCD in MATLAB (variable array)?

Tags: arrays, matlab, greatest-common-divisor

I have problem in calculating GCD. Usually GCD in MATLAB uses two variables (ex: a=19, b=88 and gcd(a,b)). But I have one variable array K = [1 1 1 1 2 1 3 2], and for this K, I want to calculate GCD.
How to calculate greatest common divisor of K ?

Comment: and result is fr=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [gcd(gcd(a,b),c) is the same as gcd(a,b,c)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66626) you can iterate through K and get the gcd of the array.

```
g = K(1)
for i=2:numel(K)
    g = gcd(g,K(i))
end
fprintf('The gcd is %i\n', g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the elements of array as elements of a symbolic vector.

For your problem-

```
K = sym([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2])
gcd(K)
```